# How to handle information overflow of man and the documentation?

Tags: configuration, services, man, daemon, software-rec

I keep asking myself how to get familiar with the software (mostly a daemon) and its configuration.

When running

```
man <program name>
```

I am very overwhelmed by the options available.

How do you or other professional system administrators learn what they need from the manual? Which steps are made by you/them to get a clear overview of the tasks to do to reach their goals? I hope there is a step-by-step guide or guideline that I can adopt or follow.

For example, I have a VPS and want to configure a proxy. I choose squid and the manual told me to go to https://wiki.squid-cache.org. I did that and get shoot by the information overflow. And squid is not the only daemon I am fighting with. I am getting confused by many services. SSH is at least under control :D

Hope you can help me with that and my concern is not worth mentioning!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix/Linux systems are complex beasts. Welcome to a wonderful world.

Check out the site of your favorite distribution, they should have some "introduction to system administration" pages. Look for the various "introduction to Unix/Linux command line" tutorials. The various GNU tools (workalikes of much of the traditional Unix tools) often come with extensive documentation in info form (can also be built as books to be printed).

The classic "The Unix programming environment" by Kernighan and Pike is a must read. Falls far short for today's much more complex environments, but it provides a solid foundation for understanding many of the more mystifying whys in Unix.

Look for texts on the systems that most interest you ([O'Reilly](https://www.oreilly.com) has series of books on salient tools).

Ask *pointed* questions. General, shopping list kind of questions, find little sympathy here.